# Flat, basic, minimalist window decorations with OpenBox or similar

Tags: arch-linux, appearance, lxde, openbox

I am currently customising my netbook's ArchLinux install. I really like the minimalist basic style of things like the [ThinMC](http://art.gnome.org/themes/metacity?page=4) window borders in Gnome, and the [FullFlat](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6971/) Firefox theme. What options are available to recreate this look on something like OpenBox or LXDE? (This is a small netbook, so I want to avoid installing loads of Gnome packages...)

Answer (score 0):

No reason to install anything Gnome to confiure your Openbox theme but you would need to install some thing if you want to make it easier on yourself. For Openbox use the [obconf](http://openbox.org/wiki/ObConf:About) package.